# SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. while printf() value of index of an array

Tags: c++, printf, segmentation-fault, dev-c++

I want to know how scanf and array works, so i create a code that print the value of each index of an array line-by-line.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char a[35];
    scanf("%30s", a);
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
        printf("index %d value :%s\n",i,a[i]);
    }
}
```

but I get an error while compiling the code. After I debug the code,
i get "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."
I'm using Dev-C++

Comment: What is the `%s` format string used for?  What is `a[i]`?

Comment: %s used for series of random characters and numbers for example "asdf12".  a[i] is value of array a index i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiling with g++ I get this warning:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:6:45: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("index %d value :%s\n",i,a[i]);
                                         ~~~~^
```

You probably want to change `%s` to `%c`, since each element of the array is a char:

```
printf("index %d value :%c\n",i,a[i]);
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much @user000001 I'm such a newbie.
By the way, when I input "asdf" why did I get some random characters like 
in a[24]='3' ; a[16]='3' ; a[9]='$'. shouldn't all the other index be '\000'?

Comment: No, it just reads whatever is in the memory following the terminating `\0`, you could get any value.

Comment: Ohhh it's all makes sense now, i have to initialize all of the elements to be \0. Thanks for the explaination @user000001

Answer (score 2):

Agree with above answer.  %s says dereference the arg and display the contents.  a[i] is using an 8-bit valiue as a pointer.